# How do I hide a particular type of user in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I am using Rails Admin gem as an admin dashboard in my rails app, it works perfectly and shows all my models. Am using devise for authentication and have two types of users, Users that signup and devise guest user (users are saved till they sign up or sign in as guest user with an example email). In rails admin Users section, it shows all of the users even the guest user. I want to hide this guest user from there.

What i tried:
**user.rb**

```
scope :verified, -> { where(guest: false) }
```

**rails_admin.rb**

```
config.model User do
    list do
      scopes [:verified]
    end
  end
```

it did not work...is there any way to use permanent filters here as my normal users have many fields like location and username...so am thinking of doing something like showing only users who have username.

Comment: Can you show the controller side code for `rails admin Users section`

Comment: there is no controller for rails admin @Toby 1 Kenobi

Comment: check in rails_admin gem, monkey patch the gem if necessary

Answer (score 0):

What you tried would filter the guest users on the list, not the access to the list itself.
The rails admin recommended way to solve this is with an authorization framework, see the cancancan documentation to get it working.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan

I successfully configured this per user.

Example of how it would work:

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    return unless user && user.admin?
    can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
    can :read, :dashboard           # allow access to dashboard
    if user.role? :superadmin
      can :manage, :all             # allow superadmins to do anything
    elsif user.role? :manager
      can :manage, [User, Product]  # allow managers to do anything to products and users
    elsif user.role? :sales
      can :update, Product, hidden: false  # allow sales to only update visible products
    end
  end
end
```